# Batch output to file with added lines

Tags: batch-file

I am trying write an output to a text file with added text.  For example i know

```
executable.exe 2> output.txt
```

will store the output of the executable in output.txt but what if in the text file i want something like:

The output of the executable is: (add some spaces) *executable.exe's output*

Answer (score 1):

How about two commands? First one to prepare file:

```
echo|set /p=The output of the executable is:     > output.txt
```

And then:

```
executable.exe 2>> output.txt
```